# Beamer Warsaw theme

Tags: beamer, templates

I would like to ask if it is possible to download Warsaw template and look inside code or if someone know how showes in header all section and subsection. I want to show in my header all section and subsection like in Warsaw theme, but I dont like other setting from that theme, so that is the reason I dont wanna use it. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You should have all the code already. Compile a small example and then look in the log-file, it should show all the files used by the theme.

Comment: I didn't find anything useful in this log-file even in .sty files.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source of the Warsaw theme at https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeWarsaw.sty

It loads the [shadow outer theme](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemeshadow.sty), which in turn gets its headline from the [split outer theme](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemesplit.sty), which you can recreate like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\makeatletter
\usesectionheadtemplate
  {\hfill\insertsectionhead}
  {\hfill\color{fg!50!bg}\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```